# How Make circle picture in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

```
child: Row(
                 children: <Widget>[
                  Image(
                    image: AssetImage('images/2.jpg'),
                    width: 100.0,
                    height: 100.0,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 20.0),
                  Text(
                    'LEXUES C300',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 30.0),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the widget CircleAvatar for it:-

```
              CircleAvatar(
                radius: 50,
                backgroundImage:AssetImage('images/2.jpg'),
              )
```

Answer (score 3):

Or use the **ClipRRect**  OR **ClipOval**

```
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(300.0),
  child: ImageAsset //
```

Answer (score 0):

Use container :

```
Container(
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: AssetImage('images/2.jpg')
      fit: BoxFit.fill
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score -2):

Use [ClipRRect](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRRect-class.html) it will work perfectly.

```
ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
        child: Image(
                image: AssetImage('images/2.jpg'),
                width: 100.0,
                height: 100.0,
              ),
    )
```